# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el tiempo transcurrido entre dos fechas de una jornada laboral con PHP y MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Es decir, el calculo solo debe considerar: de lunes a viernes de 08:30 a 18:30hrs. Tampoco días festivos, estos están en una tabla de una Db.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Cuando te refieres a 'tiempo', a qué te refieres exactamente? ¿Días hábiles, horas, minutos...?

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos.

Se trata de una plataforma de solicitudes y ejecución de órdenes de trabajo. Estas deben ejecutarse en un plazo de 48 horas laborales, de lunes a viernes, de 08:30 a 18:30. También se debe excluir días festivos.

En una tabla debo mostrar la fecha y hora de creación de cada orden de trabajo y sumarle 48 horas laborales para indicarle al trabajador la fecha y hora en que esta debe estar ejecutada. Lo complejo de este cálculo, es que está enmarcado en una jornada laboral.
Toda la información en una base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es una pregunta muy general y sin referencia de ningún tipo, ni estructura de Base de Datos; sin embargo, te puedo dar un ejemplo de un sistema de RRHH. donde en uno de esos módulos calculo este item, te recomiendo que sustituyas los arreglos aqui presentes por tus datos que vienen de la BD.

Aquí el código:

```php
<?php

function calcularTiempoLaboral($fechaInicio, $fechaFin, $horaInicio, $horaFin, $diasFestivos) {
    $tiempoTranscurrido = 0;
    $currentDate = $fechaInicio;
    
    while ($currentDate <= $fechaFin) {
        if (date('N', strtotime($currentDate)) >= 1 && date('N', strtotime($currentDate)) <= 5 && !in_array($currentDate, $diasFestivos)) {
            $horaInicioDia = strtotime($currentDate . ' ' . $horaInicio);
            $horaFinDia = strtotime($currentDate . ' ' . $horaFin);
            $horaInicioDia = max($horaInicioDia, strtotime($currentDate . ' 08:30:00'));
            $horaFinDia = min($horaFinDia, strtotime($currentDate . ' 18:30:00'));
            
            $tiempoTranscurrido += max(0, $horaFinDia - $horaInicioDia);
        }
        
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate . ' +1 day'));
    }
    
    $tiempoTranscurridoHoras = $tiempoTranscurrido / 3600;
    
    return $tiempoTranscurridoHoras;
}

// Este sería el ejemplo de uso
$fechaInicio = '2023-12-01';
$fechaFin = '2023-12-05';
$horaInicio = '08:30:00';
$horaFin = '18:30:00';

// Obtener días festivos de la base de datos (suponiendo que tengas una tabla 'festivos' con una columna 'fecha')
// $diasFestivos = obtenerDiasFestivosDesdeBaseDeDatos();

// Ejemplo de días festivos en un arreglo
$diasFestivos = ['2023-12-02'];

$tiempoLaboral = calcularTiempoLaboral($fechaInicio, $fechaFin, $horaInicio, $horaFin, $diasFestivos);

echo 'Tiempo laboral transcurrido: ' . $tiempoLaboral . ' horas';

?>
```

OBSERVACION: te comente la función "obtenerDiasFestivosDesdeBaseDeDatos()" porque seria muy propio de tu estructura pero es allí donde deberias obtenerla en forma de arreglo desde tu BD.

Comment: Disculpen lo escueto de la información entregada.

Tengo una tabla llamada ‘**solicitudes**’, con los campos:
**f_solicitud** (tipo date), fecha en que se creó la orden de trabajo.
**f_asignacion**(tipo date), fecha en que el trabajador se asigna la orden de trabajo(al hacer clic en: Gestionar) para comenzar a trabajar en ella.

Y una segunda tabla llmada ‘**fechas_festivas**’ con los campos:
**id**
**fecha_festiva**, las fechas que no se deben considerar para el cálculo.
**motivo_festividad**, para conocer el motivo de la festividad.

Comment: Intentaré incorporar la función que me enviaste.

Comment: Estimado Sr. @EloyCanifru Por favor no olvides evaluar la respuesta que le di, y de ser correcta, colocar el check para que otros usuarios la puedan aprovechar.